# layoutIfNeeded weird animation glitch

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout

I am animating a resize of a `UITextField`. I am using Autolayout with constraints. I have `H:|-[textField] -(8)-[label]-(8)-[image]-|` in constraints in my storyboard.

I animate the label flying off screen, remove the constraint between the textField and the label, and then create a new constraint between the image and the textField. 
When I animate `view.layoutIfNeeded()`, the text inside the textField glitches into the top-left corner of the textField and then animates into its normal place.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's likely that you have pending layout operations other than the constraint you're talking about. Try calling `layoutIfNeeded` once before you make the constraint changes, then add the constraints and call `layoutIfNeeded` again inside the animation block.

This will ensure that only the constraint changes you intend to animate are actually animated.

Comment: This did the trick, is there a way I can see pending layout operations?

Comment: @vrwim No idea. But you should know there are pending layout operations if you're adding constraints in the same runloop.

Comment: OMG I SHOULD HAVE USED THIS SOOOOO MUCH SOONER! THANK YOU